# Meaningfullness of matrix directions

Tags: matrices

Square matrices have a [diagonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_diagonal). They also have an [anti-diagonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-diagonal_matrix).

There are [upper-triangular and lower-triangular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_matrix) matrices. We could easily imagine an "anti-upper-triangular" matrix, such as $\left[\begin{matrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{matrix}\right]$, which is nonzero above its anti-diagonal. We can also imagine "anti-lower-triangular" matrices, which are nonzero under their anti-diagonal.

We can imagine [anti-circulant](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/74703/eigenvalues-of-anti-circulant-matrices) and anti-[Toeplitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix) matrices, which are constant along the direction of the anti-diagonal rather than along the direction of the diagonal.

So, the question: Is there a symmetry here? Can theorems involving diagonal "stuff" (and there are [many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix) of [those](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_matrix#Triangularisability)) generally be transformed into similar theorems involving anti-diagonal stuff? I suspect the answer may be "no", but if so, I'd be interested in knowing why not. Why is the diagonal direction so much more interesting than the anti-diagonal direction?

Comment: Part of the reason is that matrices that are diagonal corespond to just a number of copies of whatever ring you are working over. This is not at all the case for anti-diagonal ones (which are not even closed under multiplication).

Comment: I think, this is a consequence of the definition of the matrix-product.If we consider diagonal matrices : They probably do not have an analogue meaning if we choose the other diagonal to be the "main"-diagonal. The idendity matrix also shows that the diagonals do not have a similar meaning.

Comment: Further, if we consider square matrices as endomorphisms of a vector space with a fixed basis, then the diagonal has a nice description in terms of coefficients of vectors in the image of themselves, whereas the anti-diagonal has no such (and in fact depends on how we order the basis, which the diagonal does not).

Comment: At least, the determinant (possibly upto the sign) does not change, if we mirror the matrix.